# Creating retina screenshot programmatically resulting in non retina image

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, screenshot, retina-display

I am trying to take a retina screenshot programmatically and I have tried every approach found online, but I was not able to get the screenshot to be retina.

I understand the following private API:

```
UIGetScreenImage();
```

cannot be used as Apple will reject your app. However, this method returns exactly what I need (640x960 screenshot of the screen).

I have tried this method on my iPhone 4 as well as the iPhone 4 simulator on retina hardware, but the resulting image is always 320x480.

```
-(UIImage *)captureView
{

    AppDelegate *appdelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];


    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(appdelegate.window.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
        else
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(appdelegate.window.bounds.size);


            [appdelegate.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSLog(@"SIZE: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(image.size));
    NSLog(@"scale: %f", [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);


    return image;
}
```

I have also tried the Apple recommended way:

```
- (UIImage*)screenshot
{
    // Create a graphics context with the target size
    // On iOS 4 and later, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to take the scale into consideration
    // On iOS prior to 4, fall back to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext
    CGSize imageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
        else
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

            CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

            // Iterate over every window from back to front
            for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows])
            {
                if (![window respondsToSelector:@selector(screen)] || [window screen] == [UIScreen mainScreen])
                {
                    // -renderInContext: renders in the coordinate space of the layer,
                    // so we must first apply the layer's geometry to the graphics context
                    CGContextSaveGState(context);
                    // Center the context around the window's anchor point
                    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [window center].x, [window center].y);
                    // Apply the window's transform about the anchor point
                    CGContextConcatCTM(context, [window transform]);
                    // Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point
                    CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
                                          -[window bounds].size.width * [[window layer] anchorPoint].x,
                                          -[window bounds].size.height * [[window layer] anchorPoint].y);

                    // Render the layer hierarchy to the current context
                    [[window layer] renderInContext:context];

                    // Restore the context
                    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
                }
            }

    // Retrieve the screenshot image
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSLog(@"Size: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(image.size));

    return image;
}
```

But it also returns a non retina image:
2012-12-23 19:57:45.205 PostCard[3351:707] size: {320, 480}

Is there something obvious I'm missing? How come there methods that are suppose to take retina screenshot return me non retina screenshots?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apart from `image.size`, have you tried logging `image.scale`? Is it 1 or 2? If it's 2, it is actually a retina image.

Comment: Wow! I didn't realize an image can have a separate dimension and scale set to 2, I checked the scale on the returned image and it's 2.0, so does that mean this image is actually 640x960? And can I use this image as if its a retina image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong in your code. Apart from `image.size`, have you tried logging `image.scale`? Is it 1 or 2? If it's 2, it is actually a retina image.

[`UIImage.scale`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW39) represents the scale of the image. So an image with `UIImage.size` being 320×480 and `UIImage.scale` being 2 has an actual size of 640×960. From Apple's doc:

> If you multiply the logical size of the image (stored in the [`size`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImage/size) property) by the value in this property, you get the dimensions of the image in pixels.

It's the same idea as when you load an image into a `UIImage` with the `@2x` modifier. For example:

```
a.png (100×80)      => size=100×80 scale=1
b@2x.png (200×160)  => size=100×80 scale=2
```

Comment: I was not aware of the scale property, the scale in my image was indeed 2.0. thanks so much!