# Keep transparency in screenshot iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, screenshot

I am taking screenshot of a particular View in my Xib file with the following code...

```
UIView* captureView = self.view;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(captureView.bounds.size, NO , 0.0f);
[captureView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

It works fine and saves JPG image to camera roll.

But problem is, There is another *UIImageView* on the top of my View, that *UIImageView* has a semi-transparent image in it. 
My screenshot doesn't preserve that transparency in the screenshot it is taking. 
I want to keep the transparency as it is in the actual screen.

**How can you preserve the transparency in the screenshot?**

Comment: is the UIImageView ia a subview of captureView?

Comment: Yes , of course it is.

Comment: Please see this link... You'll see an overlay of apple image , this the image which transparency is lost..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20298887/take-screenshot-of-a-uiimage-ios

Comment: is it enough to get a single image?

Comment: The answers to this one that involve iterating through all views are a good place to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016010/creating-retina-screenshot-programmatically-resulting-in-non-retina-image

Answer (score 3):

If you specify "No" for the opaque property, your image must include an alpha channel for this to work. Check that your image has an alpha channel.

Comment: Can you illustrate how to add an alpha channel? Or help with the code.

Answer (score 2):

JPGs don't have transparency so as soon as you convert it to JPG alpha is gone.
This is a known limitation of UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum

it doesn't keep png.

Answer (score 1):

try this. this code working for me

```
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(baseViewOne.frame.size);
            [[baseViewOne layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
            UIImage * screenshota = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

also check [cocoa coder screen shots](http://cocoacoderblog.com/2011/03/30/screenshots-a-legal-way-to-get-screenshots/)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData* imdata = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_snapshotImgView.image);
UIImage* snapshotPNG = [UIImage imageWithData:imdata];

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(snapshotPNG, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```